# Jenkins job failing because of incorrect parent child pom.xml entries

Tags: java, xml, maven, jenkins

Below is the issue occurred while building project using Jenkins job, this project is having a parent pom.xml which is defining version of dependencies in it and certainly the SNAPSHOTS etc. which are imported are not required or may be a version clash.

I had a deep look into pom and no unused SNAPSHOT are there in effective pom.

Anyone having idea on what could be the problem, any debugging tips would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project script: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Effective-pom for 'com.xxx.bss.rm.invoicing.messages:compile:pom:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT' contains SNAPSHOT, failing build. Check any properties and make sure they end in .version if they specifify versions.
```

Properties in Parent pom

```
<properties>
    <coba.cdac-version>7.1.1</coba.cdac-version>
    <coba.businessentity-version>6.3.6</coba.businessentity-version>
    <com.xxx.bss.vre.version>2.8.0</com.xxx.bss.vre.version>
    <java.oam.version>R3F01</java.oam.version>
    <cil.service.version>3.0.1</cil.service.version>
    <cil.client.version>5.0.3</cil.client.version>
    <cil.messaging.version>1.0.0</cil.messaging.version>
    <bss.ctrl.jmx.monitor.version>3.0.1-E002</bss.ctrl.jmx.monitor.version>
    <bss.ctrl.version>3.0.2</bss.ctrl.version>
    <courier.version>4.1.0</courier.version>
    <com.google.code.gson.gson.version>2.3.1</com.google.code.gson.gson.version>
    <common.oam.version>1.12.0</common.oam.version>
    <com.xxx.bss.ecim.cm.observer.version>0.4.0</com.xxx.bss.ecim.cm.observer.version>
    <com.xxx.bss.osgi.srstub.serviceregistrystub.version>2.0.0
    </com.xxx.bss.osgi.srstub.serviceregistrystub.version>
    <org.osgi.service.event.version>1.3.1</org.osgi.service.event.version>
    <commons-configuration.version>1.9</commons-configuration.version>
    <com.unboundid-ldapsdk.version>3.0.0</com.unboundid-ldapsdk.version>
    <org.apache.ant.version>1.9.7</org.apache.ant.version>
    <ngee.oam.version>2.0.3</ngee.oam.version>
    <cel-version>3.7.3</cel-version>
    <avalon-framework-api-version>4.2.0</avalon-framework-api-version>
    <xalan-version>2.7.1</xalan-version>
    <xercesImpl-version>2.11.0</xercesImpl-version>
    <json-version>20140107</json-version>
    <curator-framework-version>2.10.0</curator-framework-version>
    <akka.version>2.3.4</akka.version>
    <scala.version>2.11</scala.version>
    <common.akka.version>1.0.1</common.akka.version>
    <cql3-version>2.0.2</cql3-version>
    <avro-version>1.7.7</avro-version>
    <!-- <trace.services.version>0.7.0</trace.services.version> -->
    <javax.servlet.version>2.5.0</javax.servlet.version>
    <javax.servlet.servlet-api.version>2.5</javax.servlet.servlet-api.version>
    <mock-http-server.version>3.0</mock-http-server.version>
    <hector-client.version>3.3.1</hector-client.version>
    <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>
    <junitparams.version>1.0.2</junitparams.version>
    <activemq.version>5.9.1</activemq.version>
    <!-- Changed from 2.6 -->
    <jersey.version>2.10.1</jersey.version>
    <jersey-media-multipart.version>2.5.1</jersey-media-multipart.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
    <!-- Changed from 4.3 -->
    <com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.version>4.1</com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.version>
    <com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.jersey.all.version>2.10.1</com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.jersey.all.version>
    <org.glassfish.jersey.containers.version>2.10.1</org.glassfish.jersey.containers.version>
    <org.apache.felix.eventadmin.version>1.4.2</org.apache.felix.eventadmin.version>
    <uncommons.math.version>1.2.2</uncommons.math.version>
    <apache.fop.version>1.0</apache.fop.version>
    <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
    <org.ops4j.pax.exam.version>4.7.0</org.ops4j.pax.exam.version>
    <pax.url.version>2.4.7</pax.url.version>
    <pax.logging.version>1.8.5</pax.logging.version>
    <com.xxx.bss.rm.common.datatypes.version>1.20.0</com.xxx.bss.rm.common.datatypes.version>
    <com.xxx.bss.ms.registry.version>2.1.0</com.xxx.bss.ms.registry.version>
    <bss.osgi.functioncontrol.version>2.1.0</bss.osgi.functioncontrol.version>
    <project.msv.fc.version>2.1.0</project.msv.fc.version>
    <charging.rf.core.version>1.35.0</charging.rf.core.version>
    <com.xxx.bss.osgi.trace.version>1.0.1</com.xxx.bss.osgi.trace.version>
    <cpm.cdac.dataenquirey.version>7.1.3</cpm.cdac.dataenquirey.version>
    <cpm.cdac.common.version>7.0.0</cpm.cdac.common.version>
    <rmca.cdac.version>23.1.2</rmca.cdac.version>
    <com.xxx.bss.integrationtest.utils>0.61.0</com.xxxx.bss.integrationtest.utils>
    <jive.common.version>0.0.1-alpha.62</jive.common.version>
    <karaf.version>3.0.5</karaf.version>
    <sigar.version>1.6.4</sigar.version>
    <sigar-osgi.version>1.0.0</sigar-osgi.version>
    <org.apache.servicemix.bundles.lucene.version>5.3.1_1</org.apache.servicemix.bundles.lucene.version>
    <org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jakarta-regexp.version>1.4_1
    </org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jakarta-regexp.version>
    <org-apache-xmlgraphics-version>1.7</org-apache-xmlgraphics-version>
    <org-apache-xmlgraphics-common-version>1.4</org-apache-xmlgraphics-common-version>
    <xalan-serializer-version>2.7.1</xalan-serializer-version>
    <xml-apis-version>1.4.01</xml-apis-version>
    <xml-apis-ext-version>1.3.04</xml-apis-ext-version>
    <avalon-framework-version>4.3.1</avalon-framework-version>
    <avalon-logkit-version>2.2.1</avalon-logkit-version>
    <caf-utility.version>R3B05</caf-utility.version>
    <org.eclipse.jetty.version>8.1.3.v20120416</org.eclipse.jetty.version>
    <com.springsource.javax.transaction.version>1.1.0</com.springsource.javax.transaction.version>
    <com.springsource.javax.jms.version>1.1.0</com.springsource.javax.jms.version>
    <org.eclipse.jetty.orbit.javax.servlet.version>3.0.0.v201112011016
    </org.eclipse.jetty.orbit.javax.servlet.version>
    <commons-lang3.version>3.4</commons-lang3.version>
    <com.thoughtworks.paranamer.version>2.7</com.thoughtworks.paranamer.version>
    <org.apache.felix.webconsole.version>4.0.0</org.apache.felix.webconsole.version>
    <commons-beanutils.version>1.9.2</commons-beanutils.version>
    <common-logging.version>1.1.1</common-logging.version>
    <commons-fileupload.version>1.2.2</commons-fileupload.version>
    <com.squareup.javapoet.version>1.0.0</com.squareup.javapoet.version>
    <commons-csv.version>1.1</commons-csv.version>
    <cassandra-driver-core.version>3.0.0-E001</cassandra-driver-core.version>
    <io.dropwizard.metrics.metrics-core.version>3.1.0</io.dropwizard.metrics.metrics-core.version>
    <commons-collections.version>3.2.1</commons-collections.version>
    <org.json-osgi.version>20080701</org.json-osgi.version>
    <com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.version>4.1</com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.version>
    <org.eclipse.equinox.common.version>3.6.100-v20120522-1841</org.eclipse.equinox.common.version>
    <org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.version>3.0.1-v20121109-203239</org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.version>
    <org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.version>1.1.300-v20120522-1841</org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.version>
    <org.eclipse.equinox.metatype.version>1.2.0-v20120522-1841</org.eclipse.equinox.metatype.version>
    <org.eclipse.osgi.services.version>3.3.100-v20120522-1822</org.eclipse.osgi.services.version>
    <io.netty.version>4.0.27.Final</io.netty.version>
    <io.netty.netty.version>3.8.3.Final</io.netty.netty.version>
    <msg-services.version>1.4.2</msg-services.version>
    <msg-gateway.version>1.4.2</msg-gateway.version>
    <uk.nominet.dnsjnio.version>1.0.3-E005</uk.nominet.dnsjnio.version>
    <com.typesafe.config.version>1.2.1</com.typesafe.config.version>
    <protobuf-java.version>2.5.0</protobuf-java.version>
    <scalabuff-runtime.version>1.3.7</scalabuff-runtime.version>
    <jfree.jfreechart.version>1.0.13</jfree.jfreechart.version>
    <jfree.jcommon.version>1.0.16</jfree.jcommon.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.7</joda-time.version>
    <com.google.guava.version>16.0.1</com.google.guava.version>
    <javax.ws.rs-api.version>2.0</javax.ws.rs-api.version>
    <snappy-java.version>1.1.0-M4</snappy-java.version>
    <ical4j.version>1.0.5.2</ical4j.version>
    <org.codehaus.groovyall.version>2.2.0</org.codehaus.groovyall.version>
    <javax.annotation-api.version>1.2</javax.annotation-api.version>
    <validation-api.version>1.1.0.Final</validation-api.version>
    <com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec.version>1.5.0</com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec.version>
    <org.eclipse.tycho.org.eclipse.osgi.version>3.9.0.v20130529-1710</org.eclipse.tycho.org.eclipse.osgi.version>
    <geronimo-jms_1.1_spec.version>1.1.1</geronimo-jms_1.1_spec.version>
    <org.simpleframework.simple>5.1.6</org.simpleframework.simple>
    <zookeeper-version>3.4.8</zookeeper-version>
    <kafka.version>0.9.0.0_1</kafka.version>
    <org.osgi.version>4.3.1</org.osgi.version>

    <!-- Invoice CLI -->
    <core.ui.version>1.3.0</core.ui.version>
    <charging.core.clamshell>1.5.0</charging.core.clamshell>

    <com.github.fge.json.validator>2.2.6</com.github.fge.json.validator>
    <com.github.fge.json.schema.core>1.2.5</com.github.fge.json.schema.core>
    <com.googlecode.libphonenumber.libphonenumber>7.2.2</com.googlecode.libphonenumber.libphonenumber>
    <com.google.code.findbugs.jsr305>2.0.1</com.google.code.findbugs.jsr305>
    <net.sf.jopt-simple.jopt.simple>4.6</net.sf.jopt-simple.jopt.simple>
    <com.github.fge.uri.template>0.9</com.github.fge.uri.template>
    <com.github.fge.jackson.coreutils>1.8</com.github.fge.jackson.coreutils>
    <org.mozilla.rhino>1.7R4</org.mozilla.rhino>
    <com.github.fge.msg.simple>1.1</com.github.fge.msg.simple>
    <com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson.databind>2.6.4</com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson.databind>
    <com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson.annotations>2.6.4</com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson.annotations>
    <com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson.core>2.6.4</com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson.core>
    <com.github.fge.msg.simple>1.1</com.github.fge.msg.simple>
    <com.github.fge.btf>1.2</com.github.fge.btf>
    <javax.mail.mailapi>1.4.3</javax.mail.mailapi>
    <camunda.version>7.3.0</camunda.version>
    <com.h2database.h2.version>1.4.190</com.h2database.h2.version>
    <org.mybatis.mybatis.version>3.2.8</org.mybatis.mybatis.version>
    <org.glassfish.jersey.connectors.version>2.10.1</org.glassfish.jersey.connectors.version>
    <org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient.version>4.3</org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient.version>
    <org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore.version>4.3</org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore.version>
    <com.xxx.bss.commonschemas.version>0.3.0</com.xxx.bss.commonschemas.version>
    <nl.jqno.equalsverifier.version>1.7.5</nl.jqno.equalsverifier.version>
    <org.apache.avro.version>1.7.7</org.apache.avro.version>
    <org.apache.felix.scr.version>1.8.2</org.apache.felix.scr.version>
    <org.quartz-scheduler.version>2.2.2</org.quartz-scheduler.version>
    <c3p0.c3p0-version>0.9.1.2</c3p0.c3p0-version>
    <org.codehaus.fabric3.api.commonj-version>1.1.0</org.codehaus.fabric3.api.commonj-version>
    <javax.ejb.ejb-api-version>3.0</javax.ejb.ejb-api-version>
    <org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz.version>2.2.2_1</org.apache.servicemix.bundles.quartz.version>
    <cassandra-version>2.2.6-E001</cassandra-version>
    <com.xxx.bss.rm.cpm.cdac.translation.version>7.0.0</com.xxx.bss.rm.cpm.cdac.translation.version>
    <com.googlecode.json-simple.version>1.1.1</com.googlecode.json-simple.version>
    <metrics.version>1.0.0</metrics.version>
</properties>
```

Content in child pom

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>com.xxxx.xxx.xx.xxx.top</groupId>
    <artifactId>compile</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<groupId>com.xxxx.xxx.xx.xxx.messages</groupId>
<artifactId>compile</artifactId>
<version>0.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</name>
```

I don't know whether it helps to some extent..

Goals

```
<goals>clean install -pl script exec:java -Dscript.buildName="invoicing-release" -Dscript.releaseRepository="proj-invoicing-release-local" -Dscript.stagingRepository="proj-invoicing-staging-local" -Dscript.gitWorkArea="${WORKSPACE}/.gitworkarea" -Dscript.repository="${WORKSPACE}/.scriptrepository" -Dscript.mavenSettings="${MAVEN_SETTINGS}" -B -e -Dsurefire.useFile=false --settings ${MAVEN_SETTINGS} -Dorg.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.settings=${MAVEN_SETTINGS} -Dmaven.repo.local=${MAVEN_REPOSITORY} -Dorg.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.localRepository=${MAVEN_REPOSITORY} -Djava.io.tmpdir=${WS_TMP}</goals>
```

Comment: Could you post the snippet of your parent and child poms referring to this dependency?

Comment: Yes, I can but both the files are too big in contents, I mean is it possible to you to understand?

Comment: You can just put the snippets and not complete pom's.

Comment: @RahulYadav Added some of the snippets, may be it gives some clue to you.

Comment: You have the two SNAPSHOTS - <version>0.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version> and  <version>0.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version> - right in the child pom in your question. What mvn goal are you calling in the jenkins job? Something from the release plugin?

Comment: @Michal Edited the post with goals in it, please see.

Comment: It looks like you are invoking custom Java program which is performing release. By convention it is not allowed to use SNAPSHOT jars (jars with nameversion ending on 'SNAPSHOT') in release. You have to release all intern project so that for all dependencies of your project you have jars with fix number, i.e. not ending with SNAPSHOT. For example, the

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are invoking custom Java program performing a variant of [mvn release](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/). By convention it is not allowed to release a project which has SNAPSHOT dependencies, i.e. dependencies with version ending on 'SNAPSHOT'. However, your child pom.xml refers to dependency with version `0.5.0-SNAPSHOT`. That needs to be changed to a *fix* version (one not ending on SNAPSHOT), again by convention this would be `0.5.0`. It is also likely that the version `0.5.0` of your dependency is not available yet and therefore you need to perform the release for that project beforehand.

The convention for the versioning of maven projects is as follows. During the development are jars versioned with xx-SNAPSHOT. For the xx-SNAPSHOT-versioned jars it is allowed to produce a new jar containing new features and version the new jar with the same  xx-SNAPSHOT version (i.e., replace one given xx-SNAPSHOT jar with a new one). Then once the development is finished the project will be *released* and the jar will be versioned with *fixed* version xx (no SNAPSHOT anymore). From then on the jar versioned with *fixed* version xx will not be replaced anymore. Of course if jar versioned xx is not allowed to change then also all of his dependencies must not change, i.e. all dependencies must be in *fixed* version.

Aparently the program started from the jenkins job checks if the convention is adhered to and after finding the dependency versioned `0.5.0-SNAPSHOT` it requires that this is fixed first.

Btw there is probably an error in the `artifactId` of your dependency - `compile` is usually a value for the `<scope>` element.

Comment: let me try your solution and accept the answer if it works.